# Finding only one class (stones) in aerial image using SAGA GIS

Tags: raster, classification, saga

I have a color infrared image of a mountain with trees, meadows, clusters of stones and single stones. For my work I need to identify only the pixels that cover stones, everything else is secondary. I tried supervised classification in SAGA GIS, but that requires me to specify more than one class.

What would be a method to get this done?

[image]

Comment: But what is wrong with specifying more than one class? You can discard the others later on, and it probably improves your result.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with more than one class, I was just wondering if there is a solution  that finds only one. I would still prefer it this way.

Comment: @Eric is correct.  Discarding the second class from SAGA is an easier solution to your problem then learning a new software. In any case....I am unsure if Orfeo Toolbox will accept only one class but have a look here: https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/pbclassif.html

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I will use more classes! @Erik